# exporting with dataflow

Tags: product, export, dataflow

I am trying to export products with dataflow -Profiles and want to export the field `created_at` which is in the table `catalog_product_entity`. The `created_at` drop down option from field mapping, In database: puts an empty value as the result. Even if there are values in the table.

Would be great if anyone could help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The created_at is a system field, like entity_id and a few others. See `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Parser/Product.php`, more specifically in the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    foreach (Mage::getConfig()->getFieldset('catalog_product_dataflow', 'admin') as $code=>$node) {
       // ... output omitted
        if ($node->is('internal')) {
            $this->_internalFields[] = $code;
        }
        if ($node->is('system')) {
            $this->_systemFields[] = $code;
        }
        // ... output omitted
    }
}
```

and in the `unparse()` method:

```
public function unparse()
{
    // ... output omitted
    foreach ($product->getData() as $field => $value) {
        if (in_array($field, $this->_systemFields) || is_object($value)) {
            continue;
        }
    // ... output omitted
```

Now, you have several options to export the `created_at` field, all of them requiring custom code:

1. In your module's config.xml file overwrite the `/config/admin/fieldsets/catalog_product_dataflow/created_at/system` path and set the value to 0; possibly the easiest solution here

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
> <config>
>     <!-- module stuff here -->
>     <admin>
>         <fieldsets>
>             <catalog_product_dataflow>
>                 <created_at>
>                     <system>0</system>
>                 </created_at>
>             </catalog_product_dataflow>
>         </fieldsets>
>     </admin>
> </config>
> ```

2. In your module create a new product parser, possibly extending Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Parser_Product but overwriting the `unparse` method; good if you might want some other logic for the export
3. In your module overwrite the `catalog/convert_parser_product` model and change the logic of the `unparse` method; this is just to list it as an option but option #2 is better.

Comment: wow thanks Adi for the help was really stuck I used option 1 and it worked I am just trying to understand what does setting the value to 0 do that makes it display that field?

Comment: Well, Magento doesn't allow exporting system attributes and created_at was a system attribute. Setting that value to 0 basically tells Magento that the attribute is not a system attribute, so the data flow can export it.